# What events are produced by UIControl on tvOS?

Tags: tvos

With `UIButton`, tvOS produces `UIControlEvents.PrimaryActionTriggered` (not `.TouchUpInside`, as it does on iOS) when the button gets focus and the user taps on the remote.

`UIControl`'s don't seem to produce *either* of these events, however.  I can't see that it produces any events, in fact, when the user focuses on the control and taps on the remote.

How does one use a custom `UIControl` for tvOS?

Comment: Did you try subclassing it and placing a breakpoint in `sendAction:to:forEvent:`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `UIControl` doesn't emit any control events of its own accord. Your subclass is responsible for emitting events (generally by sending itself `sendActionsForControlEvents:`).

Since `UIControl` isn't currently documented for tvOS, it might be that Apple doesn't want you to subclass it.

Anyway, I've only played around with it a little, but apparently to implement your own `UIControl` subclass, you must override `canBecomeFocused` to return `YES`, and you must override `pressesEnded:withEvent:` to act on the user's press (presumably by sending yourself `sendActionsForControlEvents:`.).

You might also want to override `pressesBegan:withEvent:` to highlight your control.

Because `UIControl` conforms to the `UIFocusEnvironment` protocol (by way of `UIView`), you can override `didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:` to update your control's appearance depending on whether it has focus.

Comment: A few nitpicks: `pressesBegin:withEvent:` should be `pressesBegan:withEvent:`, and there isn't a `setFocus:` method on UIControl. But you could override `didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:` to know when focus has changed, and see if your control is focused.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, that seems reasonable and I can try... but I'm confused: in iOS I have several examples of subclasses of UIControl which don't implement anything like sendActionsForControlEvents and just   myControl.addTarget(self, action: "touched:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside) works fine...

Comment: "it might be that Apple doesn't want you to subclass it" - FWIW the presentation on the focus engine at WWDC '16 they specifically showed an example demo of subclassing `UIControl` so I doubt that they don't want subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

I spent the last couple weeks adding tvOS support for the widgets I package with my SVG rendering library [SVGgh](https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh), so I have somewhat of a feeling for this. The issue is that there is what I think is a new or newish kind of action: UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered that gets sent out when the control wants to communicate a commitment of action, as in this response to the completion of a UIPress in my [GHButton](https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh/blob/master/SVGgh/Views%20and%20Layers/GHButton.m) class. Remember to wire up a selector to this new action in your storyboard.

```
-(void) pressesEnded:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent *)event
{
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered];
    self.beingPressed = NO;
    self.selected = self.selected;
}
```

But in a segmented control analog, the action isn't set on button push, but when the focused segment gets changed, as in the following (heavily edited for clarity) code from my [GHSegmentedControl](https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh/blob/master/SVGgh/Views%20and%20Layers/GHSegmentedControl.m) class:

```
- (BOOL)shouldUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context
{
    BOOL result =  NO;
    if(context.nextFocusedView == self)
    {
        result = YES;
        [self highlight:YES];
        if(context.focusHeading == UIFocusHeadingRight)
        {
            [self incrementValue];

            [self.parentContent.control setNeedsFocusUpdate];

            [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
        else if(context.focusHeading == UIFocusHeadingLeft)
        {
            [self decrementValue];
            [self.parentContent.control setNeedsFocusUpdate];
            [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now that I think of it, it's possible I should be sending out a UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered action in the segmented control as well but UIControlEventValueChanged seems to work the way I expect.